# Get correct "this" inside Service with dynamic function calls

Tags: angular, typescript, this

In my app I had what I thought was a clever idea where I would reuse code across 3 different functions that required the same parameter, but accessed different API endpoints with it.

I tried assigning a variable to the correct endpoint function in the service, and then calling that variable, but apparently the `this` no longer refers to the service object when the function is called via reference? I'm not sure, but the error I got was basically that `this` was undefined inside the service.

Function inside my component:

```
  submitRefurb() {
    let endpoint = this.refurbService.addRefurb;
    if (this.updating) {
      endpoint = this.refurbService.updateRefurb;
    } else if (this.refurb.id) {
      endpoint = this.refurbService.verifyRefurb;
    }
    this.loading = true;
    endpoint(this.refurb).subscribe( //This is where we have the problem
      (result) => {
        console.log(result);
      },
      (error) => {
        this.loading = false;
      }
    );
  }
```

Refurbs Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class RefurbsService {
  constructor(public httpClient: HttpClient, public sharedService: SharedService) {}
  // `this` is undefined if called like it was above
  addRefurb(refurbData, context = [this.sharedService.sectionSelected]) {
    const body = { refurb: refurbData, context};
    return this.httpClient.post(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname  + '/refurbs/add', body);
  }

  verifyRefurb(refurbData, context = [this.sharedService.sectionSelected]) {
    const body = { refurb: refurbData, context};
    return this.httpClient.post(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname  + '/refurbs/verify', body);
  }

  updateRefurb(refurbData, context = [this.sharedService.sectionSelected]) {
    const body = { refurb: refurbData, context};
    return this.httpClient.post(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname  + '/refurbs/update', body);
  }
}
```

Now, I finally got it to work by simply assigning the `endpoint` variable as a string, rather than directly assigning it to the function, like so:

`let endpoint = 'addRefurb';
...
this.refurbService[endpoint](this.refurb)`

But I'm still not fully understanding what went wrong, can anyone explain what the difference is? Is there a better way to handle it than the way I ended up doing?

Comment: try calling the `endpoint` function like this: `endpoint.call(this, this.refurb).subscribe( .. )` and see what happens

Comment: @OsmanCea Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't that bind it to the `this` of the Component rather than the `this` inside the RefurbService?

Comment: Correct... I misunderstood you wanted to bind it to the component `this`. Anyway, if you want to bind it back to the service, just replace `endpoint.call(this, this.refurb)` with `endpoint.call(this.refurbService, this.refurb)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `bind` method :

```
 submitRefurb() {
    let endpoint = this.refurbService.addRefurb.bind(this.refurbService);
    if (this.updating) {
      endpoint = this.refurbService.updateRefurb.bind(this.refurbService);
    } else if (this.refurb.id) {
      endpoint = this.refurbService.verifyRefurb.bind(this.refurbService);
    }
    this.loading = true;
    endpoint(this.refurb).subscribe( //This is where we have the problem
      (result) => {
        console.log(result);
      },
      (error) => {
        this.loading = false;
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Accepted this as the answer as it showed a standard EC5-compatible way of doing it, although I do think I prefer the approach that @OsmanCea commented, using endpoint.call(this.refurbService, this.refurb) rather than binding each of the 3 assignment, as it's less repeated code.

Answer (score 1):

Use an arrow function:

```
let endpoint = (refurbData) => this.refurbService.addRefurb(refurbData);
```

Or just store the observable rather than the endpoint:

```
let obs = this.refurbService.addRefurb(this.refurb);
...
obs.subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Very good answer, it was hard to choose between this and the other one, but I went with the other mainly because it more directly followed the original code, with only minor derivation, and was the more "low-level" ES5 javascript solution.

Both of these were solid, clean solutions though, and I'll be sure to keep them in mind in the future.

Just a quick question on the 2nd option, wouldn't this run the service's function each time assignment occurs, up until the actual server call, or is the remaining logic only ran when subscribed to?